# HAProxy with Multiple SSL Chooses Wrong Certificate

Tags: ssl, load-balancing, haproxy

I have a problem where sometimes HaProxy chooses the wrong SSL certificate. The scenario is this, I have 3 domains:

```
domain1.com
domain2.com
domain3.com
```

Each domain goes to the same backend, all ssl termination happens on the load balancer. Also each domain has it owns pem file in the designated pem folder.

Sometimes domain2.com will try to use domain1.com certificate, and same for the other domains. A simple refresh fixes it but it shouldn't be. Here is my config:

```
global
   log /dev/log local0
   log /dev/log local1 notice
   chroot /var/lib/haproxy
   stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
   stats timeout 30s
   user haproxy
   group haproxy
   daemon
   maxconn 10048
   tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

defaults
   log global
   mode http
   option forwardfor
   option http-server-close
   option httplog
   option dontlognull
   timeout connect 5000
   timeout client 2000000
   timeout server 2000000

frontend http_front
   bind *:80
   stats uri /haproxy?stats
   reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
   default_backend http_back

frontend www-https
  bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/pems/ #All PEMs here, in seperate files
  reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
  default_backend http_back

backend http_back
   redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
   balance roundrobin
   server sprout1 x.x.x.x.:80 check
```

What am I missing in my config?

Comment: you've probably solved this already but I'd guess you have combined more than one certificate in a pem file. Make sure they're named domain.pem and haproxy will autoselect the one you want.